# Vue2 error: "Unknown custom element: <gmap-infowindow>"

Tags: google-maps, vue.js

How do you declare a gmap-infowindow inside a Vue component?

I have a GmapMap component that seems to be declared in the main.js file. Inside this component I want a Hover component that house an info component. I do not know how to declare the info component so I get the error "Unknown custom element: "

```
// main.js
Vue.use(VueGoogleMaps, {
  load: {...}
)

// site_maps.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <GmapMap>
       <HoverTooltip \>
    </GmapMap>
</div>
</template>

// hover_tooltip
<template>
  <div>
    <gmap-infowindow
      :position="pos"
    >{{ text }}</gmap-infowindow>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `InfoWindow` component is globally registered under the name of [`GmapInfoWindow`](https://github.com/xkjyeah/vue-google-maps/blob/9030066db70bad40152d77d34b24838b6ac086fb/src/main.js#L72) instead of "GmapInfowindow"; so in your template, change this `<gmap-infowindow>` into `<gmap-info-window>`. Unless you registered it locally, with different name (which doesn't seem to be the case).